# Synchronize two timers with multiple instances (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm a newbie in Java and I haven't work with threads in past. Now I have a really tricky issue for my level of knowledge.

I have developed two functionalities the "Send mail" and the "Check mail". Each user register his preferences and the system creates two catalogues with many instructions for periodic work like

A) send message every 1500 msec

B) send message every 1800 msec

C) send message every 3000 msec

And 
A) check message every 2000 msec

B) check message every 6000 msec

C) check message every 8000 msec

I tried many ways with threads but I fail to do it work. 
My question is which is the best way to synchronize them? Below is code from my last effort using threads.

```
public class MailCreatorThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        CreateMail(_date); //creates a mail with _date as subject
    }
}

public class GPSThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (!_isTimeToStop) {
            try {
                while (_servicesToUpdate.size() == 0) {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
                _currentService = (MyService) _servicesToUpdate.get(0)
                        .clone();
                _servicesToUpdate.remove(0);

                        MailCreatorThread mailCreatorThread = new MailCreatorThread();
                        mailCreatorThread.start();


            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CheckServicesThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (!_isTimeToStop) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                    for (int j = 0; j < _servicesList.length; j++) {
                        MyService currentService = ((MyService) _servicesList[j]);
                        if (myService.getTimeToNextUpdate() - 1000 <= 0) {
                            _servicesToUpdate
                                    .add((MyService) currentService
                                            .clone());
                            currentService
                                    .setTimeToNextUpdate(currentService
                                            .getUpdatePeriod());
                        } else {
                            currentService
                                    .setTimeToNextUpdate(currentService
                                            .getTimeToNextUpdate() - 1000);
                        }
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to run thos periodic tasks. The syntax is fairly straightforward:

```
Runnable check = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        checkMessage();
    }
}
Runnable send = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        sendMessage();
    }
}

//since what you are doing is mostly I/O you probably want to have 
//more than one thread available so that if one operation blocks,
//the other ones can be launched in parallel

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(check, 0, 1500, MILLISECONDS);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(send, 0, 6000, MILLISECONDS);
```

Note: `Timer` mentioned in [Ozzy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10196234/829571) should not be used any more as it has been improved in Java 1.5 by `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, as explained in [Timer's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) :

> Java 5.0 introduced the java.util.concurrent package and one of the concurrency utilities therein is the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor which is a thread pool for repeatedly executing tasks at a given rate or delay. It is effectively a more versatile replacement for the Timer/TimerTask combination, as it allows multiple service threads, accepts various time units, and doesn't require subclassing TimerTask (just implement Runnable). Configuring ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with one thread makes it equivalent to Timer.

Answer (score 3):

In java you have built-in Timer and TimerTask classes to help you repeat a task in a separate thread.

This will create a Timer which will create its own background Thread:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
```

You can then schedule as many tasks as you want to that timer, they will share the timer's own thread.

This is how you can schedule a single task on the timer thread, after a delay of 2000ms = 2s:

```
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //task to perform
    }
}, 2000);
```

This is how you can schedule a **repeated** task on the timer thread, after a delay of 1s, and repeat the task at 1.5s intervals:

```
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //task to perform every 1.5 seconds
    }
}, 1000, 1500);
```

Now you have a choice to schedule both tasks (checkMail, sendMail) to the same Timer (same thread) or give them each their own Timer (separate threads).

For more info, refer to the java docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should recommend using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` instead of `Timer` for Java 1.5+ - see my answer.

Comment: Ozzy thank you for your time! 
I tried your solution and it works exactly as you describe
but after some search in java i retrieve that as assylias says ScheduledExecutorService is the recommended tool.